# Recording macros in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, database

I recorded a macro converting number formatting with a pivot chart about 100 cells and tried running that macro on another pivot chart with much more cells but only a few converting. Does the macro only affect the number of cells with which it was first recorded with?

I recorded the first `macro1` but I would like it to fit to range of `macro 2` so that I don't have 2 macros doing the same thing just because there are more cells in one pivot chart.

[image: Code of both Macros]

Comment: Open the vbe and you can see the code.  It is a literal copy of ever action so, most likely it will only format the same cells as you recorded.  If you want help on changing the code to fit your needs.  edit the question with the code that was recorded and specifically explain what it is doing and what you need it to do.

Comment: please put the code as text, we cannot copy paste a photo.

Comment: @ScottCraner I've edited the question if you'd like to take a shot at it. Would like to hear your feedback.

Comment: the easiest way would be to remove the first line in each of the macros, then select all the cells yourself that you want to format.  with those cells selected run the macro.

Comment: @ScottCraner Remove the "ActiveCell" line or "Sub Macro" Line?

Comment: activeCell line